# importing Parse API in android stuio

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to import the Parse API into my project following the directions on their website. However android studio still cannot resolve a Parse object. I even tried invalidated caches and restarting android studio and it still cannot resolve the Parse object. My code used to import the Parse API in the Android Manefest, gradle.build, and the main activity are listed below. Also if I would need to provide more lines of code to help solve the problem please let me know.

gradle.build lines:

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+' compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
```

Manefest lines:

```
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Main activity

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this); 

Parse.initialize(this, "tqvmXNMZl5MhmQMOJVGoPlXdpOoXvLw4L1m4ipnk", "y93yzhXfY6DG3H4G4eqSk29ysSTCv459JIHPbPEk");
```

Comment: Are you adding all the permissions, receivers, services on your manifest?

Comment: Did you sync with Gradle after adding adding the jar to the libs directory and adding the compile line to the build.gradle?

Comment: @cd33 Did you able to resolve Parse.class?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to check the maven repo that 'bolts' archive of yours is contained in  and check for "allprojects.repositories" in top level gradle build that points to the repo with bolts.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral() //OR where is Bolts
    }
}
```

OR just use a Jar include for the parse stuff as belo...

On AS 1.0.1 android projects with parse...

Structure of proj...
./libs contains parse-1-1-3.jar

So, to pick up the jar...
build.gradle has

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.1.3.jar')
```

then your java files, you should be able to

```
import com.parse.abcdefgOrWhatever
```

in the IDE  sync and rebuild should work

outside the IDE CLI  ./gradlew $task    should also work
assuming that the import handled the gradle wrapper config OK.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

**1** Download the Parse SDK from [here](https://parse.com/docs/downloads) **NOT** [here](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new)

**2** Unzip the SDK and copy the parse jar file to your project's `libs` folder

[image]

**3** Add the dependencies in your project's `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
}
```

**4** Add the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**5** Copy these to your main activity's onCreate method:

```
 // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    //Am assuming you have created an app on parse.com, 
    //copy the `Parse.initialize` code specific to your app and replace it with this one 
    Parse.initialize(this, "blablabblablabla", "blablabla");

    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("foo", "bar");
    testObject.saveInBackground();
```

Make sure your device is connected to the Internet. Then run the app.

Finally, test to see if your app successfully sent the parse object by clicking on the `Test` button in the download link provided above:

If successful, you should see this:

[image]